# Filter Records in a file based on first column value through AWK/SED

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following records:

```
a,1

a,1,2

a,1,2,3

b,4

b,4,5

b,4,5,6
```

I want the output like this:

```
a,1,2,3

b,4,5,6
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Would you like some fries with that?

Answer (score 1):

It's really unclear what you are trying to do here. It's even less clear what you have tried so far (good StackOverflow questions usually involve some *code*)! You've read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), right?

If your input is in a file called `input_file.csv`, then the following `awk` program will give you the output you have said you want. Whether it will work for your real data is anyone's guess.

```
% awk -F',' '{
    lines[$1] = $0
}
END {
    for (line in lines) {
        print lines[line]
    }
}' input_file.csv
```

I offer no explanation as to what this simple script does, but a handy [reference for awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Thanks for your appreciation!

Comment: @Anonymous: Delighted to have been of use!  "Thanks for the code, it is working vey well" is best expressed around here [as a green check mark to the left of the most helpful answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

As requested

```
awk '/......./' input
a,1,2,3
b,4,5,6
```

Comment: Nice work, @Fredrik! Why not save yourself a few keystrokes? `awk '/.{7}/' input`